# google places search methods inconsistencies

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I have a question about how google places handles search requests.

This is the situation:
There is an app that looks for atm machines in a specific location. The lookup is handled with the following url:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=49.338233,11.04442199999994&radius=1000&keyword=atm|geldautomat&sensor=false&key=KEY

This works well enough.

Now this atm lookup has to be transported into a web application using js. I am using the places api but I just can't figure out how to get the same results.

For instance:
Using `new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map).search(request, callback)` with the same parameters as above in the link the results will differ greatly! For some locations I get more results, for other locations I get less or null results back.

I have tried to use a combination out of

```
search (using keyword-parameter)
radarSearch (using type atm)
nearbySearch (using type atm, too)
```

but these will produce too many results (e.g. banks which don't have atm machines). Also, I'd like to avoid firing three requests where one should suffice.

I'd very much like to just use the url from above but that conflicts with the same origin policy. And as far as I can tell google prohibits jsonp in their v3 api standard.

So, the question is:
Using the current v3 js api of google places: How do I simulate the request that is done by the url above?

Answer (score 0):

I've added **rankby** parameter into a request settings and got the same results as from URL:

```
var request = {
    location: default_center,
    radius: 1000,
    rankby : google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
    keyword: 'atm|geldautomat'
};
```

Please check [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/giftedev/2qqc3m07/) and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That is true. The results are the same. I just don't get why the search lookup in the app gets other results. The algorithm looks just the same... Well, that is another case I guess. Thanks for answering, though. I'll grant you the bounty to acknowlege your effort.